# Get string between starting and ending between hash value example: #insidehash# will be insidehash

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have long string and I need to extract subsrting which will start and end with # in c sharp

For example: `#insidehash#`
Substring will be: `insidehash`

I am looking solution for the above problem

I have long string and I need to extreact subsrting which will start and end with # in c sharp

For example: #insidehash#
Substring will be: insidehash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to match and extract substrings that start and end with #.

Below are example code:

```
 string input = "#insidehash#";

 string pattern = @"#([^#]+)#";
 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
 foreach (Match match in matches)
 {
     string extractedSubstring = match.Groups[1].Value;
     Console.WriteLine(extractedSubstring);
 }
```